# html div scrollbar error

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome

how to apply z-index position to html scroll bar.[image]

The problem is the scrollbar showing the backround text.

the problem occurs only in google chrome browser.

Comment: can we see some code? also, what have you tried?  Quick note:  z-index only works on non-static elements.  So you may need to give it a position attribute

Comment: Is your div above the text or is the text above div ?
First case : Try changing opacity (if set to less than 1.0)
Second case: Try changing z-index of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent container of the scrollbar has opacity < 1.0 which means all children of that container will have at the most that opacity.

How to fix it?

Use two containers.

```
<div> <!-- Position this centrally, i.e what you have, but 1.0 opacity and no background -->
  <div></div> <!-- textarea/div with overflow & scrollbars here -->
  <div></div> <!-- content here with background color, opacity < 1.0 etc -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Z-index does not work without proper positioning.  Try adding `position: relative;` to that textarea element.

Comment: we given scrollbar to a div not to the textarea.we given the position : relative to that div. still no use

Comment: What browsers is this happening in?

Comment: The problem is only in the chrome browser.